# Database SQL one to many, how to select latest from many table?

Tags: sql, sequelize.js

I have a two tables with one to many relationship

`products` - store product info

**| id | name |**

`status_histories` - store the product status histories

**| id | product_id | status | note | created_at |**

One `product` can have many `statuses` through time

Example data:

products

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | blue shirt |
| 2 | red shirt |

status histories table

| id | product_id | status | note | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | draft | init | 2023-02-01 |
| 2 | 1 | reviewed | all looks good | 2023-02-08 |
| 3 | 1 | live | go live! | 2023-03-01 |
| 4 | 2 | reviewed | everything looks fine | 2023-03-05 |

Now I want to search products by status, how do I do that? e.g

- search status by **live**, it will return product 1
- search status by **review** it will return product 2

In the search result, I want to return all information about the product and the status

Comment: Do you want a SQL or Sequelize answer? Can you show us your current code attempt?

Comment: So you only want to consider the latest status for each product?

Comment: @NickW Yes, the only latest status of each product

Comment: @jarlh Obviously Sequelize will be the best, but if that's not possible or not performant, then raw SQL is fine, I thing I tried is using the .findAll with include in Sequelize, or `select product_id, status, max(created_at) from status_histories group by product_id, status` then second SQL to get the product info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including the product name is a simple join.  You can use a row_number function to identify the latest row (n=1):

```
select sh.*, p.name, row_number() over (partition by sh.product_id order by sh.created_at desc) n
from status_histories sh
join products p on p.id = sh.product_id
```

Or wrap the above in the n=1 filter like this:

```
select t.* from (
    select sh.*, p.name, row_number() over (partition by sh.product_id order by sh.created_at desc) n
    from status_histories sh
    join products p on p.id = sh.product_id
) t where n = 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that, its almost there, but when I tried to use the wrap query it said syntax error at or near "=",  around n = 1, I'm using Postgres, do you know how can I fix that

Comment: probably need to alias the subquery.  I will add a 't' to the code

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8993e/5).

Hint - I have some points that won't fit in a "comment"...

I noticed few modeling issues in your table design.

1-We don't know if you have a FK or not between IDs

2-You have probably used a "date" data type for created_at, the better way is to use a timestamp so that you can provide for multiple status change in the same date to be clear.

3-We don't know how the id column on "status histories" table is generated. Is it generated automatically by the DB?

4-The name "status histories" is not a good name. I suggest you use single name and use the word "product". How about "ProductStatus". Also, I would use "Product" instead of "Products".

5-You need to create a non-unique index on the timestamp for efficient performance if you have large data.

6-We don't know which database system you are using.

Comment: thanks for that! it's helpful for me. Yes I left out a lot of things in the table design (its using Postgres). 1. No fk, 2. yes timestamp will be used, 3. id is auto increment, 4. Agreed, it can be better name, 5. I'm very interesting in this bit, what do you mean, can you give me example? so an index is needed on the `created_at`?

Comment: @vitohuang, creating an index on a column where you use queries is almost a must for large data. If you don't the database may have to search the rows 1 by 1 and you never want to do this if you use the query often. Indexes are usually created on Primary Keys and Foreign Keys and columns you sort on to enhance performance, and in times to enforce uniqueness as it is the case for PKs. Each index has a name, its best if you use good names.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a CTE that gives you the latest version of each product and then query the CTE. Something like:

```
WITH prod_latest (id, product_id, status, note, created_at) AS (
    SELECT id, product_id, status, note, created_at
    FROM status_histories sh
    WHERE sh.created_at = (
        SELECT MAX(sh1.created_at)
        FROM status_histories sh1
        WHERE sh.product_id = sh1.product_id
        )
)
SELECT *
FROM prod_latest
WHERE status = 'live';
```

Comment: What about getting the product name from the products table? Do I have to be in separate query

Comment: What if there were 2 status values in the same date?